# Can't see HoloLens emulator in Universal app

Tags: .net, windows-10, visual-studio-2017, hololens, hololens-emulator

I have installed the emulator and can see it when I open one of Microsoft's sample projects, but in my project the HoloLens emulator is not listed. My app is an Universal Windows Platform app and targets Creators Update as well as the min version. Why is this?

[image]

Here is the installed Emulator

[image]

Comment: Is the platform set to **x86**?

Comment: no it is set to x64

Comment: Change it to you then.

Comment: I compiled it for x86, restarted VS and nothing changed

Comment: Did you installed the emulator?

Comment: The min n max version don't look right to me, try to use what's in the sample.

Comment: According to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-targetdevicefamily I am right with my versions in the manifest

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not installed the HoloLens Emulator Please go to the following link to download the Emulator first

[Hololens Emulator Download](https://hololens.reality.news/how-to/hololens-dev-101-install-set-up-hololens-emulator-0174845/)

Comment: I did. And I can see it when I load a Hololens project from Microsoft's github samples for Windows 10.